# QueryFilter not working in DynamoDB

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query all queued notifications of my table 'notifications' table in DynamoDB.

```
Global Secondary Indexes: Name: idTo-time-index
Hash Key: idTo (Number)
Range Key: time (Number)
```

Why I'm getting all results and not only the ones with `status=='queued'`?

```
$params = array(
    'TableName' => 'notifications',
    'IndexName' => 'idTo-time-index',
    'KeyConditions' => array(
        "idTo" => array(
            "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array('N' => 1)
            ),
            "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ"
        )
    ),
    'ScanIndexForward' => false,
    'QueryFilter' => array(
        "status" => array(
            "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array('S' => (string)"queued")
            ),
            "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ"
        )
    ),
);

$response = $dynoClient->query($params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solve that problem by updating the ASW SDK, the reason is that query filter was added recently, in my old SDK when i execute the same query then Query filter was not working.

```
Updating the SDK should solve your problem
```

Hope that helps